# Does the "test" property take precedence over the "excludes" configuration list in Surefire?

Tags: maven-2, surefire

In surefire, if I name a test in the "test" property that overlaps a pattern in the "excludes" config, will it get executed?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By trial and error I think I've proved that the "test" property does take precedence.

However, if an include list and exclude list are both defined in config and they overlap then the exclude list will take precedence.